# ADO.NET Project

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

I'm trying to create a project which is basically a library management system.
As a display I used the standard DataSource to WinForm drag and drop system, which displays everything shown in the SQL table.
I want the users to be able to see the content of each row in the grid by double clicking it, which would redirect to another page with the selected row number and information to be displayed on each field.
As for the admin side, I want to be able to modify my db (delete, insert).
Is this the right path, or should I draw a grid from scratch?

Also, my SQL table contains images, this is what's bugging me. 
The default gridview shows the little red X's in the varbinary column, and I can't seem to get rid of that.
Regarding inserting data into the table, is there any way to add images directly from the system above? Or should I redirect to a new page and code the respective into textboxes and things of the sort?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Let me remind you that asking too many questions makes your whole question a good candidate for closing as _too broad_ As a new user you should really read carefully the [help] before asking

Comment: You can build custom datasource objects that just contain the columns you want.